# Trying to add and delete a clone somehow not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im really struggling to find what is going wrong here its just not quite adding up i have another cloning example in my code but i swear they are the same yet this one is not working?
http://jsfiddle.net/a4KZs/

```
$("#addArrival/Departure").click(function(){
        $(".question21:last").after($(".question21:first").clone(true));
    });

    $("#deleteArrival/Departure").click(function() {
        if($(".question21").length!=1)
        $(".question21:last").remove();
    });

<div class="questiontext">
                    22. Arrival/Departure Details<br>
                </div>
                <div id="question21" class="input">
                    <div class="question21">
                    Arrival Date<br>
                    <select id="selectday4" class="daydate">
                        <option>Day</option>
                    <script>
                        var select = document.getElementById("selectday4");
                        var options = new Array();
                        var temp = 1;
                        for(var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
                            options.push(temp);
                            temp++;}
                        for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                            var opt = options[i];
                            var el = document.createElement("option");
                            el.textContent = opt;
                            el.value = opt;
                            select.appendChild(el);}
                    </script>
                    </select>
                    <select id="selectmonth4" class="monthdate">
                        <option>Month</option>
                    <script>
                        var select = document.getElementById("selectmonth4");
                        var options = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
                        for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) 
                        {
                        var opt = options[i];
                        var el = document.createElement("option");
                        el.textContent = opt;
                        el.value = opt;
                        select.appendChild(el);
                        }
                    </script>
                    </select>
                    <select id="selectyear4"  class="yeardate">
                        <option>Year</option>
                    <script>
                        var select = document.getElementById("selectyear4");
                        var options = new Array();
                        var firstyear = (new Date().getFullYear()) - 18;
                        var temp = firstyear;
                        for(var i = 0; i < 83; i++) {
                            options.push(temp);
                            temp--;}
                        for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                            var opt = options[i];
                            var el = document.createElement("option");
                            el.textContent = opt;
                            el.value = opt;
                            select.appendChild(el);}
                    </script>
                    </select><br>
                    City/Port of Arrival<br>
                    <input type="text" name="arrival/departure" class="textbox"><br>
                    Flight/Ship<br>
                    <input type="text" name="arrival/departure" class="textbox"><br>
                    Departure Date<br>
                    <select id="selectday5" class="daydate">
                        <option>Day</option>
                    <script>
                        var select = document.getElementById("selectday5");
                        var options = new Array();
                        var temp = 1;
                        for(var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
                            options.push(temp);
                            temp++;}
                        for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                            var opt = options[i];
                            var el = document.createElement("option");
                            el.textContent = opt;
                            el.value = opt;
                            select.appendChild(el);}
                    </script>
                    </select>
                    <select id="selectmonth5" class="monthdate">
                        <option>Month</option>
                    <script>
                        var select = document.getElementById("selectmonth5");
                        var options = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
                        for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) 
                        {
                        var opt = options[i];
                        var el = document.createElement("option");
                        el.textContent = opt;
                        el.value = opt;
                        select.appendChild(el);
                        }
                    </script>
                    </select>
                    <select id="selectyear5"  class="yeardate">
                        <option>Year</option>
                    <script>
                        var select = document.getElementById("selectyear5");
                        var options = new Array();
                        var firstyear = (new Date().getFullYear()) - 18;
                        var temp = firstyear;
                        for(var i = 0; i < 83; i++) {
                            options.push(temp);
                            temp--;}
                        for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                            var opt = options[i];
                            var el = document.createElement("option");
                            el.textContent = opt;
                            el.value = opt;
                            select.appendChild(el);}
                    </script>
                    </select><br>
                    City/Port of Departure<br>
                    <input type="text" name="arrival/departure" class="textbox"><br>
                    Flight/Ship<br>
                    <input type="text" name="arrival/departure" class="textbox"><br>
                    Country of Destination<br>
                    <input type="text" name="arrival/departure" class="textbox"><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="adddeleteArrival/Departure">
                    <div id="addArrival/Departure">
                        <input type="button" value="Add Arrival/Departure"> 
                    </div>
                    <div id="deleteArrival/Departure">
                        <input type="button" value="Delete Arrival/Departure">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: You may want to explain to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an invalid id selector, the `/` in the `id` has to be escaped using `\/`

```
$("#addArrival\\/Departure").click(function () {
    $(".question21:last").after($(".question21:first").clone(true));
});

$("#deleteArrival\\/Departure").click(function () {
    if ($(".question21").length != 1) $(".question21:last").remove();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NXcxg/)

*Note: In the fiddle you didn't include jQuery library*

Comment: @user2430661 you have syntactical errors... unclosed brackets... see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Jd337/1/ ... as the first step of debugging see the browsers console to check whether there are any errors